# enum ConsoleColor - is that type?

Tags: c#, enums, console

I know I can set property **ForegroundColor** of consele but what I am not sure is: the property is of the type `enum` or **ConsoleColor**, which is enum? I just do not know what I am exactly doing, setting the property to value of consolecolor (what is this, instance of enum? enum?).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is of type `ConsoleColor`, which is an enum type.

When you set it with something like:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

you're setting it to a value of type `ConsoleColor` - just like anything else. `ConsoleColor.Red` is a value of type ConsoleColor in the same way that 3 is a value of type `int` and `"hi"` is a value of type `string` (although in the latter case it's a reference to an object, whereas enums are value types).

In particular, you have to set it to a value of type `ConsoleColor` rather than any other enum. For example, this won't compile:

```
// This would be crazy
Console.ForegroundColor = FileShare.ReadWrite;
```

Comment: So, I need to set this property of any value of the Console.Color, which means to some of its constants, ok?

Comment: @Mojmir: Not `Console.Color`, `ConsoleColor` - very different.